# Session in OC4J (9.0.4.1) and OC4J (10.1.3.1)

Tags: jsp, oc4j

I wrote a very simple JSP file in order to check the Session in OC4J (9.0.4.1) and OC4J (10.1.3.1). I found that:

- [OC4J 10.1.3.1] Session keeps changing when web page is REFRESHED
- [OC4J 9.0.4.1] Session is maintained even web page is REFRESHED

Anyone has clue to solve this issue ?

---

The source codes are as follows:

Session ID is <%=session.getId()%>

Answer (score 0):

In v10 Can you check the value of the `shared` attribute in `<web-app>` tag in your default-web-site.xml or *-web-site.xml

```
<web-app application="myApp" name="myWebApp" root="/myApp/" shared="true" />
```

The default is false. Does it return same sessionID when set to true?

Comment: Thanks. Those MyApp, myWebApp are arbitrary names of my applications? If not, how can I set those names?

Thanks

Comment: You'll have to replace the actual names of your applications instead of myApp/myWebApp in your -website.xml file.